# Mysql doesn't use index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I tried to make indexes on my table. But First mysql uses it then that doesn't use the index.

It is my table indexes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQKuY.png-)

My Query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT K.bayiid) AS toplam,
SUM(K.tutar) AS yatirilan,
SUM(IF(K.durum='2', K.tutar*K.toplam,0)) AS kazanc,
SUM(IF(K.durum='-1', K.tutar, 0)) AS kayip,
SUM(IF(K.durum='1', K.tutar,0)) AS devam,
SUM(IF(K.durum='0', K.tutar,0)) AS iptal,
SUM(1) AS oynanan,
SUM(IF(K.durum='2', 1,0)) AS kazanan,
SUM(IF(K.durum='-1', 1,0)) AS kaybeden,
SUM(IF(K.durum='1', 1,0)) AS devameden,
SUM(IF(K.durum='0', 1,0)) AS iptalolan,
U.*
FROM kuponlar AS K 
INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.id = K.bayiid AND U.durum != '4' AND U.id = '26689'
WHERE K.durum < 3   AND K.tarih >= '2016-12-01 00:00:00' AND K.tarih <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Query explaination
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHFGb.png)

But i don't want to use USE INDEX or FORCE INDEX. Do you have any idea why mysql works unstable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ON U.id = K.bayiid 
AND U.durum != '4'
AND U.id = '26689'
```

For clarity, move the last 2 parts to `WHERE`; leave only the condition(s) that defines the `JOIN`.

```
WHERE K.durum < 3 
  AND K.tarih >= '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
  AND K.tarih <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Suggestion:  For date ranges, do something like this:

```
  AND K.tarih >= '2016-12-01'
  AND K.tarih  < '2016-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

For `K`, have

```
INDEX(bayiid, darum)
INDEX(bayiid, tarih)
```

(Without knowing the distribution of the data, I cannot predict which is better.  The Optimizer will choose.)

If you want to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  If there happen to be datatype inconsistencies, that could cause a lot of trouble, and we cannot see it without the `SHOW`.

[*Indexing cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)